# Object comprehension in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

```
const obj = {}
arr.map((e) => {
  obj[e.title] = e.someBool
})
```

Is there a shorter way of doing the above in Javascript?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: `var obj={};arr.map(e=>obj[e.title]=e.someBool)` Voilà, it’s shorter. Now, in seriousness, don’t abuse `map`; this is a job for `forEach`.

Comment: If you're looking for a python-style syntax, there is not. I would use a regular `for-of` loop, or `Array.forEach` (no new array cretaed), but other than that, you'll have to pack this into a custom function

Comment: If you're doing a general dictionary in ES6, you should use a `Map`, not an object, and those can easily be constructed from key/value pairs.

Comment: Not shorter, but clearer: `arr.reduce((acc, val) => (acc[val.title] = val.someBool, acc), {});`

Comment: ^ This. `map` is a wrong way to do this. It creates an array which will never be used. If you need a loop, use for or forEach.

Comment: @str - yeah, `reduce` is probably the best solution, however I'd argue it's not actually clearer to the lay-programmer. The behavior of `reduce` and the comma notation instead of semi-colon are not exactly common knowledge.  So... a little magical.  A matter of taste, though, I admit.

Comment: @broofa I agree with the comma notation, but `reduce` is an important feature that everybody can easily find the documentation for.